# Issue with rails production, rails console not showing updated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, production, puma

So I am using rails with puma and nginx as my reverse proxy and server for a rails API server.
Every time I make an update on my files , such as updating the model , or controller. I've discovered that my files weren't updating on to production. Discovering this, I found out that I had to restart my puma and nginx each time i made a change.

After i restart both puma and nginx , i see that my APi server looks updated. So i decided to check the console  through "rails c production"  and I discovered that it couldn't load any of the models and would just keep returning me

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Post
    from (irb):1
```

Fiddling restarting my servers back and forth , or maybe a period of time , it would magically work on it's own and my files would be updated. Could someone explain to me how do I update my rails production server ? and why is this happening.

Comment: You can check rails console through `RAILS_ENV=production rails c `

Comment: @Vishal yes , i am getting the error mentioned above still.